# how can I change style of bootstrap modal in a panel modal?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i would like to know how can I transform the simple modal in a panel modal samples please... I need to make a panel modal for my work. or even how can I use bootstrap dialog with form inside..

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this, Panel inside of Modal window.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Panel inside of Modal window</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Panel title</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I meant the same panel design as my modal not panle inside of modal